# Selenium test with behat and mink in symfony 3 on vagrant virtual machine

Tags: symfony, selenium, behat, mink, symfony-3.2

I have symfony 3.2.6 app. I have some buttons that make ajax calls so I need to test them with selenium. I installed and configured behat and mink. With standard functional tests without javascript everything works fine. 
I have my context class that extends MinkContext.
My feature file have @javascript tag on top of test. In my virtual machine in /var/www/selenium folder I run selenium server with this command:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar
```

This is my behat.yml

```
extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        goutte: ~
        selenium2:
            wd_host: http://myapp.dev:4444/wd/hub
        base_url: http://myapp.dev
        javascript_session: selenium2
        browser_name: firefox
```

When I run

```
php vendor/bin/behat --tags @javascript
```

I get this error:
Could not open connection: Cannot find firefox binary version '9' in PATH
        Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32'

And if I change browser_name: safari I get this:
Could not open connection: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{deviceType=tablet, selenium-version=2.31.0, marionette=false, browserVersion=9, browser=firefox, name=Behat feature suite, browserName=safari, deviceOrientation=portrait, ignoreZoomSetting=false, version=9, platform=ANY, tags=[myapp.puphpet, PHP 7.0.18]}]

I installed xorg-x11-server-Xvfb, java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64, http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar and firefox.

Did I missed any step?

EDIT:

I run this command:

```
yum -y install firefox Xvfb libXfont Xorg
```

and also this one:

```
yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop"
```

I downloaded selenium 2.53.1. If I run startx I get this error:

> (gnome-panel:15453): Gtk-WARNING **: A floating object was finalized. This means that someone
>   called g_object_unref() on an object that had only a floating
>   reference; the initial floating reference is not owned by anyone
>   and must be removed with g_object_ref_sink().

When I run

```
nohup java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

I get

> nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

If I run

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

I get

> Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   09:22:37.189 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
>   09:22:37.190 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
>   RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
>   09:25:11.183 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running

I tried with ff 52.1.0-2, 45.8.0-2 and 45.7.0-2.

And if I run behat test while selenium server is running I get

> Could not open connection: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Comment: The `Gtk-WARNING` is just that, a "warning" only, not a error. The `nohup` is what you typed on the command line and this is expected. So the only real error is "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JAR version 2.53, see my article for more details:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/using-mink-to-perform-functional-tests-in-symfony3-framework/

The older JAR supports the older versions of FireFox on Linux.
Here's the link to the 2.53.1 JAR you will need:
https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

---

EDIT #2 based on comments

Make sure you run this in another console:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

This is because you are running:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question because I still have some errors. I would appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: Did you `export DISPLAY=:1` in another console window??? I can update my post if that fixes the problem. Please try to do more troubleshooting before posting and asking question. I spent a lot of time on research before I got this working. It was not easy - plus I didn't "ask" for help but figured it out on my own.

Comment: Yes, it solved it. You can add it to answer for further reference . Thanks.

Comment: And just one note - if selenium server won't start add this as option when starting server -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom switch